# Naive Implementation of Automatic Memoisation

Tags: python, beginner, functional-programming, memoization

I wrote code to (naively) perform automatic memoisation. I tried to write it in a functional programming style, and so did not make use of any global variables.

### My Code

```py
def naive_memoise(caches):
    def memoise(f):
        nonlocal caches
        def mem_f(n):
            nonlocal caches, f
            if f not in caches:
                caches[f] = {}
            if n not in caches[f]:
                caches[f][n] = f(n)
            return caches[f][n]
        return mem_f
    return memoise
```

#### Sample Usage

```py
def fib(n):
    if n in [0, 1]:
        return n
    return  fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)

mem = naive_memoise({})
fib = mem(fib)
```

Comment: Is there any use case in which you would want to initialize the cache with something other than an empty dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me and I have nothing important to add.

- the `nonlocal` are not required here
- in the code sample, you could use the `@decorator` syntax
- maybe you could write something more generic than just functions taking a single parameter.

Comment: I could change the parameter of `mem_f` to `*lst` I guess so it could handle functions with multiple arguments. It would requires rewriting the functions that work with it though. Not sure I know a general way to do it without customising the functions to be memoised so they interface well with the memoisation closure.